# JDBC Template ничего не возвращает

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-jdbc

Имеется подобный SQL запрос, который хранится в `String`:

```java
private static final String SQL_STATEMENT =
        "SELECT name FROM matched_records mre " +
                "INNER JOIN clusters c on mre.cluster_id = c.id " +
                "INNER JOIN matching_rules mru on mru.id = c.rule_id " +
                "WHERE mre.etalon_id = '?'";
```

В ходе работы программы я его немного меняю, а именно на место `?` подставляю другую строку (id - строка)

Когда же пытаюсь получить результат через `jdbcTemplate.queryForList`, он мне ничего не возвращает, хотя в этот же самый момент я выполняю SQL запрос, который мне изменяет программа и он возвращает результат

```java
String query = SQL_STATEMENT.replace("?", etalonId);

List<String> rulesNames = template.queryForList(query, String.class);
```

В `rulesNames` должен быть список строк, которые удовлетворяюсь запросу, однако их там не находится.

Опять же повторюсь, когда выполняю этот же самый запрос к БД (который получаю из значения переменной `query` путем копирования и вставки в консоль БД), то он результат возвращает.

Comment: Попробуйте вообще убрать часть запроса после `WHERE`, чтобы понять, проблема в фильтрации и условии, или вы, например, соединяетесь не с той БД. Какую БД используете? Вторая частая проблема, что не закомитили изменения сделанные в сессии консоли БД, потому их не видно из программы.

Comment: Тут вообще есть над чем подумать. Во первых если объявляется константа, то значение переменной поменять нельзя. С другой стороны, если взять переменную и подставить ее у запрос то, такое работать не будет, потому, что шаблон запроса нужно отредактировать путем добавления необходимых параметров, с учётом их типов. А вы пытаетесь делать `replace()` без всякого понимания структуры данных. Вставлять вручную текст не то же самое, если делать это программно. И это не безопасно, так как можно подхватить SQL injection уязвимость.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Используется Postgres. В случае, который вы описываете, изменения бы не отобразились и при обычном SQL запросе, однако если я делаю запрос через консоль (тот же самый), то результат есть

Comment: @RomanC Спасибо за замечание с ```replace()```. Обязательно его учту. Что же касается неизменяемости строк, то метод ```replace()``` возвращает новую строку, причем в дебаггере я вижу, что она изменена.